# Cursor in wrong position when editing

Tags: texstudio

I just installed MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio 2.9.4 on a relatively new Windows 8 machine.

Whenever I try to edit text, the cursor is about a tab away from the text. When I go back and edit text the position of the cursor is shown to be about a tab away from the location that edits are actually taking place. This makes editing very difficult.

I've used TeXstudio for a long time on other computers but have never seen this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't see the problem on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem today. I figured, the reason for my problem is the dual monitor settings. Because the two monitors have different "scales". one is 150%, the other one is 120%. I unplug the other monitor and the problem just went away. (I also re-installed the program several times, so.... i don't know which one is the solution.) but lets try

Comment: This seems flaky, and is perhaps better-suited as a comment.

Comment: Still worked for me. I mean the reason you said. I just restarted the program.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing a recent update of TexStudio (had been working with a version around 2.2 for a while and decided to finally update to the latest stable 3.0 version).

Playing with the zoom did not help for me. What did solve the problem on my end was to choose a "Monospaced Font":

[image]

Doing so reduces the set of fonts you can choose from and I wish there was a solution that would allow me to use other fonts. But until I find a better fix, I really need Texstudio to work so I'll just have to live with it.

Weirdly enough, some people seem to have a similar problem in Overleaf: https://support.mozilla.org/bg/questions/1263396?&mobile=0